# C# Failing to append a character onto a string, but only in one method

Tags: c#, string, sockets, tcp, plc

I'm writing a TCP solution between a PLC and Unity3d simulator. I'm having the most perplexing issue simply appending a ';' onto the end of a string in which I send to the PLC.

Here's my code:

```
public void extractSpeed(string PLCSpeed) { //coneverts the socket message to belt speed and assigns it to belt
    if (!isRollers) {
        Int32.TryParse(beltScript.convID, out int j);

        if (j < 10) {
            convID = "0"+beltScript.convID;
        }
        if (j >= 10) {
            convID = beltScript.convID;
        }
    }
    if (isRollers) {
        Int32.TryParse(rollerScript.convID, out int j);

        if (j < 10) {
            convID = "0"+rollerScript.convID;
        }
        if (j >= 10) {
            convID = rollerScript.convID;
        }
    }
    if (PLCSpeed.StartsWith("B"+convID)) { 
        string finalPLCSpeed = PLCSpeed.Substring(4, 4);
        finalSpeed=float.Parse(finalPLCSpeed);
        //finalSpeed=finalSpeed;
        start = true;
        Debug.Log("Extracted Speed to Belt "+convID+": "+finalSpeed);
        testString = PLCSpeed;
        testString += ";";
        Debug.Log("TestString: "+testString);
        socket.sendData(testString);
        return;
    }else { //catch invalid message
        //Debug.Log("Failed to extract speed!");
        return; 
    }
}
```

As you can see,

```
testString = PLCSpeed;
        testString += ";";
        Debug.Log("TestString: "+testString);
        socket.sendData(testString);
        return;
```

is where I attempt to append the ';' to the string. When I log the value, I get the original string with no ';'. When I send the value to the PLC I get the original string as one message and a second message with just ';'. Other methods work fine and send fine. It's just this method, even when I append the message at the sendData method in my socket script, all messages get the ';' except the data sent from this method. I am also able to send much longer strings in one message as well so I don't believe it's due to buffer length or anything. The strangest part is I log every message I send via sendData, yet it does not log sending a ';', but I receive it as a separate message on the PLC.

Bear in mind, The data inside the PLCSpeed tag is always B+ID+Speed. Ex: B010300.

I added the ';' onto the string inside the PLC as I send this string to Unity and then once I set the speed, I send it back to the PLC for verification. When I place the ';' in the PLC it works fine, but I still cannot append any string onto the end of PLCSpeed. It's as if it's marked constant but it isn't.

Comment: This is the debug.log returned from Unity when I set the testString to this:
    Debug.Log("TestString: "+testString +"Test"+";");

I get: "TestString: B010150"

Comment: Code shown is not [MCVE] (as it missing actual value in addition to being non minimal)… I strongly suspect you doing something wrong with your data transfer and put extra `\0` in your strings...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov All these strings contain B+ID+0000 where 0000 is speed and almost always ends in a 0. I have not \0 in any string. Should I have that for strings that end in 0? I changed the data sent from the PLC to have a ';' and it appears in the data but nothing is able to add to the string still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp I figured it out thanks to @AlexeiLevenkov.

The PLC was sending \0 x 256. It's due to my buffer being 256bytes. I couldn't see them because C# handles them as spaces or something. using String.Replace I was able to detect them visually.

The Log:

"Data:B010150;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

So there we have it. PLC's are a nightmare to do anything with and Sockets are the most extreme of nightmares.

Thanks for the help!